# Unable to Share a URL through Bluetooth(UIActivityViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, airdrop

I'm trying to share a URL so that URL should be opened in Safari or any web browser but unable to do so. I have Sent that to my MAC and MAC opening it as text file and then by clicking on that i'm going to safari but in case of iPhone i'm struggling to open it.In case of NSURL my app crashes with some exception. Here is my code

```
NSString *url=@"www.google.com";
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];

// Exclude all activities except AirDrop.
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,
                                UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

// Present the controller
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
NSString *url=@"www.google.com";
```

to:

```
NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
```

If this doesn't work for you because of a crash it's likely a problem elsewhere, but make the crash report available and maybe I can help.